# How to set maxlength for a unicode textbox in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application I have a textbox which accepts unicode character/non unicode character.

If any unicode character enters it should validate it against the max length of 15.

How can I differentiate a normal text and unicode text entered in the textbox in c#? Whether it needs any extra length like in **sql server varchar and nvarchar size varies**.

```
<asp:TextBox ID=txtInput runat="server" MaxLength="15" TextMode="MultiLine">
</asp:TextBox>
```

How to restrict the length of textbox against the unicode character?
Do I need to specify seperate max length for unicode and non-unicode string so that it should not exceed max of 15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you use `nvarchar` or `varchar`, you don't need to use another max length for Unicode.

if you use `varchar`, then any Unicode char will considered non-Unicode and counting will not be different.

if you use `nvarchar`, then any char will considered Unicode and counting will not be different.

Comment: how can i set textbox to a non-unicode or unicode type? i need to validate the contents of a asp.net textbox which may contain unicode character. but it should not exceed 15 in mumber.

Comment: @user1547670 as you are done,only `MaxLength="15"` for `TextBox` for your goal is enough.

Comment: my question is Do I need to specify seperate max length for unicode and non-unicode string so that it should not exceed max of 15? ie: character `a` in unicode and non-unicode will take up the same space?

Comment: @user1547670 simply you don't need! ie: character `a` in unicode and non-unicode will take up the same space.

Answer (score 1):

How can I differentiate a normal text and unicode text entered in the textbox?

```
string text = txtInput.Text;
foreach (char c in text)
{
    int unicode = c
    if (unicode > 128) 
    Console.WriteLine("character is unicode" + unicode);
}
```

and then you can validate character or anything you want.